use torch.sum to calculate mask area based on image
enter image description hereI am using based on yolov7 to implement code. I calculate each mask area by using the torch.sum method. I found some of result is not right. In this image, red color rectangle "1.shape" is smaller than "4.shape", "1.shape" value of value is bigger than "4.shape" of area value.
My code is as below:
for j, (*xyxy, conf, cls) in enumerate(reversed(det[:, :6]), start=0):
    x1,y1,x2,y2 = xyxy
    b_width = x2-x1
    b_height = y2-y1
    bbox_size = b_width * b_height 
    c = int(cls)
    mask = masks[j] #Assuming class indices start from 1
    mask = (mask > 0).float()
    total_pixels = mask.numel()  # Total number of pixels in the mask (assuming 2D)
    mask_area =  torch.sum(mask).item()
    percentage_area = round((mask_area / total_pixels ) * 100, 2)
    total_percentage_area+=round(percentage_area,2)
    each_item = (bbox_size /total_pixels)*100

I am no idea for those area value. why is happen on this area value?
